# Traits return type

Tags: php, traits

I've been trying to specify the return type of a function inside of an `interface` does `PHP` lack support for this or am I missing something?

```
<?php interface AInterface { public function F() : self; }
```

When I implement the `interface` above the following causes a fatal error regarding mismatching declaration:

```
<?php class A { public function F() : self { return $this; } }
```

Edit: I'm aware that removing the `: self` inside of the `interface` fixes the error but does that mean there is no way to ensure the return type using interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not implement the interface and also You have some confusion on the use `self`;

> self does not refer to the instance, it refers to the current class.

This is what I guess want to achieve :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kourouma
 * Date: 12/08/2018
 * Time: 17:35
 */
interface AInterface { public function F() : AInterface;}

class A implements  AInterface { public function F() : AInterface { return $this; }}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->F()); // empty object
```

**The Return Type Declarations RFC has this to say:**

> The enforcement of the declared return type during inheritance is
>   invariant; this means that when a sub-type overrides a parent method
>   then the return type of the child must exactly match the parent and
>   may not be omitted. If the parent does not declare a return type then
>   the child is allowed to declare one.
>
> ...

[Read more here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types#variance_and_signature_validation) 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that return type accept anything that `implements AInterface` though? Cause I'm trying to only accept the return type `A/$this/self`

Comment: Unfornately no from what I know and See from the RFC